# Powershell ping indefinitely

Tags: powershell, ping

In Powershell is there a better way to ping a host indefinitely besides doing something like this:

```
$max = [System.Int32]::MaxValue
ping host -count $max
```

The '`%WINDIR%\System32\ping.exe`' has a '`-t`' option to ping until Ctrl-C is pressed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
while (1) {
   ping host
}
```

This will ping indefinitely until you press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd> just like `ping -t` would.

Comment: `while (1) { ping host -count 1000 }` has the nice side effect of hiding most of the ping statistics.

Answer (score 8):

There is nothing at all wrong with John T's answer, but I will point out just for completeness sake that ping.exe is still there so this would work just fine in PS as well:

```
ping.exe host -t
```

Answer (score 3):

in windows powershell you can use `Test-Connection` cmdlet.

> This cmdlet sends ICMP echo request packets ("pings") to one or more
>   computers using WMI

although it does not have any `-t` option but it have `-count` option that u can indicate number of ICMP pocket to send
instead you can use this cmdlet this way:

```
while (1) {
   Test-Connection host
}
```

and result is like bellow:
[image: Test-Connection Powershell Command result]